# Installing Oracle 11g XE on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, ubuntu, oracle-xe

I have spent the last 6 hours trying to install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu. Obviously, I'm not the only one who has struggled with this, as there is a lot of (often misleading) "documentation" online on how to resolve the various errors that one invariably encounters when installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu.

I followed one such "guide" - [(this one)](http://www.len.ro/work/oracle-11g-release-2-xe-on-ubuntu-12-04/), and followed all the instructions. I then spent the last 5 hours trying to configure Oracle, to no avail.

when I run `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`, I got the response (after a few minutes):

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details
```

Here are the contents of the files in my /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log folder:

**CloneDbCreation.log**

```
Control file created.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ORA-01109: database not open 


Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes                                       
Fixed Size                  2233344 bytes                                       
Variable Size             616565760 bytes                                       
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes                                       
Redo Buffers                5541888 bytes                                       

Control file created.


System altered.


Database altered.


Database altered.


System altered.


System altered.


Database altered.


Tablespace altered.


TABLESPACE_NAME                                                                 
------------------------------                                                  
USERS                                                                           


       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
         1 oracle@jupiter (PMON)                                     1          


         2 oracle@jupiter (VKTM)                                     1          


         3 oracle@jupiter (DIAG)                                     1          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
         4 oracle@jupiter (DIA0)                                     1          


         5 oracle@jupiter (DBW0)                                     1          


         6 oracle@jupiter (CKPT)                                     1          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
         7 oracle@jupiter (RECO)                                     1          


         8 oracle@jupiter (MMNL)                                     3          


         9 oracle@jupiter (VKRM)                                     7          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
        10 oracle@jupiter (CJQ0)                                     5          


        87 sqlplus@jupiter (TNS V1-V3)                               3          
SYS                                                                             

        88 oracle@jupiter (PSP0)                                     1          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
        89 oracle@jupiter (GEN0)                                     1          


        90 oracle@jupiter (DBRM)                                     1          


        91 oracle@jupiter (MMAN)                                     1          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
        92 oracle@jupiter (LGWR)                                     1          


        93 oracle@jupiter (SMON)                                     1          


        94 oracle@jupiter (MMON)                                     3          



       SID PROGRAM                                             SERIAL#          
---------- ------------------------------------------------ ----------          
USERNAME                                                                        
------------------------------                                                  
        98 oracle@jupiter (QMNC)                                     5          



19 rows selected.


User altered.


User altered.


System altered.
```

**CloneRmanRestore.log**

```
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes                                       
Fixed Size                  2233344 bytes                                       
Variable Size             616565760 bytes                                       
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes                                       
Redo Buffers                5541888 bytes                                       

TO_CHAR(SYSTIMEST                                                               
-----------------                                                               
20121127 08:47:46                                                               

Allocating device....                                                           
Specifying datafiles...                                                         
Specifing datafiles...                                                          
Restoring ...                                                                   
Restore done.                                                                   

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


TO_CHAR(SYSTIMEST                                                               
-----------------                                                               
20121127 08:48:17
```

**PostDBCreation.log**

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


File created.

Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes                                       
Fixed Size                  2233344 bytes                                       
Variable Size             616565760 bytes                                       
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes                                       
Redo Buffers                5541888 bytes                                       
Database mounted.
Database opened.

'UTL_RECOMP_BEGIN:'||TO_CH                                                      
--------------------------                                                      
utl_recomp_begin: 08:49:11                                                      


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


'UTL_RECOMP_END:'||TO_CH                                                        
------------------------                                                        
utl_recomp_end: 08:49:13
```

**postScripts.log**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY dbms_sumadv_lib AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libqsmashr.so';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


BEGIN dbms_datapump_utl.replace_default_dir; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


create or replace directory XMLDIR as '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/xml'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


DROP DIRECTORY ORACLE_OCM_CONFIG_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


DROP DIRECTORY ADMIN_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


DROP DIRECTORY WORK_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


BEGIN dbms_swrf_internal.cleanup_database(cleanup_local => FALSE); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

My environment variables are as follows:

```
root@jupiter:~# env | grep ORACLE
ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/
```

Miscellaneous system configuration:

```
root@jupiter:~# df -k /dev/shm
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
shmfs            2097152 624008   1473144  30% /dev/shm


root@jupiter:~# sysctl -p |grep kernel
kernel.shmmax = 1073741824
```

I don't know what else to do. I have come to the end of my tether. Hopefully, all of the above will mean something to an Oracle expert, who can point out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part is unusual:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/
```

This needs to be char-by-char identical every time. I see it ends with a slash here, which is non-standard, and I suspect that you've added it by mistake. Adding a slash will result in "ORACLE not available" in so-called bequeath sqlplus, I've just experimented on my system. Try again with one consistent setting like:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
```

Comment: Erm, I don't know what to say ... I followed your instructions and went off to make a cup of coffee - fully confident that when I returned, I would have an error message. So convinced I was that I even forgot to check again. 15 minutes later, I remembered, and nonchalantly toggled screens to see what the latest error message. To my absolute shock. It said **Installation completed successfully**. You Sir, to me, are a GOD!

Comment: +1 for zeroing in on the exact problem, through the reams of information I provided in my question.

Comment: Good catch! That would've had me scratching my head for a little while.

Comment: Good catch, the trailing slash of ORACLE_HOME has had me puzzled on more than one occasion.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli kudos goes to you for gathering all the  information; given the size of Internet, someone will figure it out sooner or later, if all the necessary *input* is at hand

Answer (score -1):

Once investigated the log files, prompted in the log files, I was able to notice that the `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST` destination directory in `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init*` did not exist. So I manually created the directory.

In my case

```
sudo mkdir /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area
```

This has been applied within both `init.ora` and `initXETemp.ora`.
Restarted the Laptop and started the the configuration again.

`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Above completed the configuration successfully for me.